# Convert Java-Class to JavaScript for Node.js

Tags: javascript, java

I have a curiouse Java-Class, i misunderstand the handling, you will see why.

These class i want to convert to JavaScript for using under Node.js for the new client/server architecture.

For the first, the class comes from an old Java Client. Here, the Data will packed/unpacked with these class. If you send an "Hello World", the class will add the length "11" (because "Hello World" has an lengh of 11) as first byte entry. The Package-result is `[LENGTH][DATA]`.

Here is the class:

```
public class Protocol {
    public static byte[] decode(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        byte first = (byte) in.read();

        if (first == -1) {
            throw new IOException("End of stream");
        }

        int length;

        if (first >= 0) {
            length = first + 1;
        } else {
            length = (first & 0x1F) + 1;
            int count = (first & 0x60) >>> 5;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                length += in.read() << (i << 3) + 5;
            }
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
        in.read(buffer, 0, length);
        return buffer;
    }

    public static byte[] encode(byte[] message) {
        int length = message.length - 1;
        byte[] len;

        if (length < 128) {
            len = new byte[] { (byte) length };
        } else {
            int count = 0;

            while (32 << (count + 1 << 3) <= length) {
                count++;
            }

            count++;
            len = new byte[count + 1];
            len[0] = (byte) (count << 5 | 0x80 | length & 0x1F);

            for (int i = 1; i < len.length; i++) {
                len[i] = (byte) (length >>> 8 * (i - 1) + 5);
            }
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[len.length + message.length];
        System.arraycopy(len, 0, buffer, 0, len.length);
        System.arraycopy(message, 0, buffer, len.length, message.length);
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

For sample, here is an call:

```
byte[] packet = Protocol.encode("Hello World".getBytes());
anOutputStream.write(packet);
```

**Yet, my question:**

If the message length is `<= 127` (or here, `< 128`), the length will appended as a single byte on `index 0`. But i misunderstand the other Part. I hope you can clarify these.

The second question is: **Why will be checked on decoding, if the first byte is over `0`?**

It's a logical problem on my side: the byte (see [Java: InputStream.read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--)) returns **only two values**: `-1` for "End, nothing more to read" or an byte value of `0-255`. But why, these will be checked? Because, the other part will never called, so i think.

I hope you can help me to understand these class.

Comment: I guess it encodes a number that does not fit into one byte into two bytes (uint16), 4 bytes (uint32) and so on

Comment: But why, the decoder says all the time "if the first byte >= 0, set the header length to bytevalue+1"?